# How to use a non-USB router as a wireless print server for a host based printer

Tags: wireless-router, network-printer

- **Router Model**: [DSL-2730U](http://www.dlink.co.in/pdfs/products/DSL-2730U/DSL-2730U_ds.pdf)
- **Router Ports**: LAN and DSL, No USB port
- **Printer**: [Canon Imageclass MF3010](http://brochure.copiercatalog.com/canon/mf3010-specsheet.pdf)
- **Objective**: To convert this USB printer into wireless by using the router as a wireless print server.

The solution I planned:

1. Connect the printer's USB cable to the router through a USB-female to RJ45-Female connector.
2. Then Update the router's firmware to one which allows wireless print server, like Openwrt or similar (will try a bunch of them to check).

Theoretically, will the above solution work, assuming nothing else goes wrong. What I have been reading on various forums is that a) it is not possible to convert an RJ45 port into an USB port. b) it is not so easy to turn a host based printer wireless. Hence my skepticism of the solution above.

Any other solution will also be much welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, you can't with the method you're thinking. Ethernet sends a very different signal than USB.

What will work is having a computer or print server that is always on, connected to the router and the printer. There are many cheap USB print servers available online if you do not have a computer that is always on and connected to your router.